# Install tuleap on amazon ec2 linux AMI

Tags: linux, centos, amazon-ec2, tuleap

I'd like to know if it's possible to install tuleap on amazon ec2 linux ami. I searched the net unsuccessfully and when I try to install tuleap with yum, I get conflict errors (with httpd24, php55-common,...)

I tried to remove the conflicting packages but the error is still the same...

By changing yum repos with the Centos ones (+ rpmforge, remi, epel, tuleap), I can't update the glibc and glibc-common packages which seem to be the problem...

`package glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.i686` is required but the package `glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.x86_64` is installed and i can't replace it...

Anyone had a successfull feedback of tuleap installation on amazon EC2 AMI?

I tried with Linux AMI and RHEL AMI; Ami Linux 2014.03 and Redhat 7. I'm trying now on Redhat 6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

Using the Redhat RHEL 6.5 AMI, and following the [full installation guide](http://doc-en.tuleap.net/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html#installation) in the Tuleap documentation but I had to yum update after setup of epel and rpmforge.

I didn't test all the features yet but the setup went well and i can access the UI from the web.